# What part of speech is "as their native"?

Tags: english, grammar, parts-of-speech, phrases

In the sentence:

> The number of people who speak English *as their native* language will decline.

what part of speech is *as their native*?

Comment: "part of speech" is an analysis of lexical items, not phrases. So, none.

Comment: It's an adverbial phrase.

Answer (score 4):

*The number of people who speak English **as their native** language will decline.*

The string *as their native* comprises three separate items: the preposition "as", the genitive pronoun "their" and the adjective "native". 
It is not itself a constituent, but part of the preposition phrase *as their native language* headed by the preposition "as".

Comment: Are you sure that *as* is used as a preposition here and not as an adverb? Might as well be that I'm wrong.

Comment: I would think that a prepositional use would be something like "It is used [as an introductory textbook]" or "John dressed [as a penguin] for Halloween" where the phrase behaves more like an argument to the verb, while "They speak English [as their natie language]" or "I bought a new printer [as a replacement]" behaves more adverb(i)al in that they modify an NP. Although PPs themselves can as well have adverbial function, but I would think that the lexical category of *as* here is rather an adverb.

Comment: It's a typical prep taking an NP complement. Adverbs don't normally take genitive NPs as complement. The adverb "as" is typically used in comparative constructions like _Anne is **as** tall as Mary_. Some also see it as a subordinator when it introduces subordinate clauses.

Comment: But wait: Is the whole NP actually genitive? Shouldn't it be just the poessessive pronoun?

Comment: (Because you'd ask for "as what"/"as who" and not "as whose".)

Comment: *As* here is a preposition which takes predicative complements as opposed to objects. The adverb *as* is a deictic degree adverb, which is nothing like the usage here. Notice that there are not two separate entities here *English* and *native language*.  Unlike prepositions, generally speaking, adverbs do not take complements. Notice that the word *as* must take a complement here, otherwise the sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

As @user6726 already said, you can not assign the phrase a POS, because "part of speech" refers to single words which *as their native language* isn't.

---

If you are interested in the syntactic category, you could say it is a **prepositional phrase**, because the head of the phrase is *as* which is a preposition<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

*as* is a **preposition**, *their* functions as a determiner (its POS would be a possessive **pronoun**), *native* is an **adjective** and *language* a simple **noun**.

---

You can however **not** assign a category to *as their native* like you wrote, because this is not a constituent: You can not separatedly group the words together like this.

W.r.t. the tree this means that there is no node which dominates
a) all these terminals
b) and nothing else but these terminals.

If you don't find this so intuitive, you could also think about grouping all words that somehow belong together into brackets:

> [ [as] [ [their] [ [native] [language] ] ] ]

All the words could be "groups" on their own, *their native language* forms a group next to *as*, *native language* is a group and the whole phrase is one as well, but you will find no pair of brackets that contains exactly *as their native*: It is not a constituent, this combination of words is not a separable phrase. You'd need to include the noun *language* as well or narrow it down, saying e.g. that *as* is a preposition.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup> *as* can also be used as an adverb, as in *My house is not AS big as yours*; however, as @PaulM and @Araucaria pointed out, adverbs don't take (NP) complements, so the use here must be prepositional.
Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @Araucaria Okay, you and PaulM have conviced me. I'll change my post and my tree.

Comment: +1 from me. I think your post would be better without the credit (although it's generous of you :-))

Comment: @Araucaria I don't know, I felt it would be kind of unfair to make it look like this was all my ideas when it was due to helpful comments that I could improve my answer, so I think it better to mention it ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the example "The number of people who speak English as their native language will decline", "as their native language" is a manner adverb, which makes it a V-bar modifier, following the analysis in McCawley's *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*.  The V-bar modified is "speak English".

Syntacticians generally identify syntactic categories, or parts of speech, by checking out "privileges of occurrence".  We compare other phrases with similar senses that could be substituted.  Here, we could substitute for "as their native language" such phrases as "natively", "fluently", "in a fluent manner", and so on.  This makes it evident that it is a manner adverb.  For describing manner adverbs as V-bar modifiers, please see McCawley's discussion.

The idea that we use "part of speech" only to classify single words and not also phrases, expressed by several other commenters, might have been true long ago, for the ancient Greeks, but is no longer so.  Times change.

Comment: I basically understand your reasoning, but I think you did not sufficiently elaborate the difference between the choice of the category of *as* (where the categorisation in the comments as a preposition rather than an adverb was motivated by the fact that the latter generally can't take NP complements) and the syntactic behaviour (to be identified, amonst others, by the substitution tests you mentiond) of the phrase: It makes a difference whehter a *word* is an *adverb* or a *phrase* behaves *adverbially*.

Comment: Labelling the phrase as a PP because its head has more properties of a preposition does not per se exclude the possibility that the constituent has an adverbial function in the sentence; the choice of terminology is then rather unlucky in etymologically implying that any adverbial originates from the word class of an adverb, which I recently had a discussion on in a different question, but the mere fact that PPs just as well as e.g. NPs, which can by no means be classified as adverbs (and the category of the phrase more or less unarguably needs to match the category of its head), ...

Comment: ..., can have an adverbial function in the sentence, does not force its *head* (and with that, the phrase it constitutes) to be caterogised as such. This could not explain the phrasal status of adveribal NPs such as in *I go hiking [most weekends]* - you wouldn't want to call *most weekends* an adverb only because the phrase has an adverbial meaning in the sentence.

Comment: @lemontree, You write "(and the category of the phrase more or less unarguably needs to match the category of its head)".  I hope you'll spend some time thinking about this, because it's not so.  I'm sure you can come up with counterexamples to this "law".

Comment: No, I really can't: In the theory of syntax I have in mind, such a tree would simply not be well-formed, because determining its phrase's category is part of the *definition* of a head. If you don't presuppose the classical X-bar notions of constituency (which I assumed since you're talking about V-bar-modifiers), you'd have to tell me what such counterexamples are. What would a phrase be for you? Does it have a head, and if so, how is that head determined if it doesn't reflect the phrase's syntactic category? Do you assume a tree-like structure at all or do you consider this outdated as well?

Comment: @GregLee "as their native language" is surely a phrase and not an adverb, even if you want to call it an adverbial?

Comment: @Araucaria If I understood his point correctly, he indeed wanted to say that the whole phrase is an adverb, because his claim is that POS terms are applicable for phrases also.

Comment: @lemontree Under this type of analysis the PoS/phrase label is given by the grammatical relations, not the type of phrase. So you can have nouns that are adverbs, nouns that are adjectives and so forth. Some people think that a better way of labelling stuff is to have one label for the type of word or phrase and a distinct and different label for the syntactic function /grammatical relations. This avoids saying that this giraffe is an elephant and so forth. ...

Comment: @lemontree ... (Because of course after that if someone says that X is an elephant you never know if it's a baboon being an elephant, or an elephant being a giraffe  Unless, of course,  they explicitly state that its a downstairs baboon and an upstairs elephant or a downstairs elephant and an upstairs giraffe)

Comment: @lemontree, it is of course true that if you take the relationship between, e.g., N and NP or V and V-bar to be axiomatic, then it will always hold.  But then this part of your theory has no empirical content -- you're not talking about natural language any more, but just about your own ideas.  If you're not prepared to consider evidence, I see nothing here to discuss.

Comment: @Araucaria, How do you know that "as their native language" is "surely a phrase and not an adverb"?  Is there any fact about English you can give us in support of what seems so obvious to you?  (What about the constraint on coordination that coordinated constituents be of the same category?)

Comment: @GregLee The constraint seems to be that the coordinates be of the same syntactic function.

Comment: @Araucaria, Why does it seem that way to you?

Comment: @GregLee Well, straightforwardly, your "upstairs" designation is basically a grammatical function disguised as a word or phrasal category. It is the grammatical function which seems to determine what can coordinate with what, and this is what leads to a certain circularity (looking at it from my point of view) in your word/phrase labelling. You give them the same upstairs word or category label when they perform the same type of syntactic function(s). But then you also say "what about the constraint that coordinated constituents be of the same category".

Comment: @Araucaria, I don't agree that there are two different things in language, what you are now calling "grammatical function" versus "word or phrasal category"..  Of course, there may be two different things inside your head, evidently there are, but linguistics is about evidence. ("Upstairs" and "downstairs" both refer to how constituents combine -- "upstairs" refers to how a containing constituent combines.)

Comment: @GregLee By 'containing' constituent, I assume you mean how your constituent relates to larger constituents around it. And by 'downstairs' I assume you mean how the internal bit's of that constituent fit together?

Comment: @Araucaria, No, that is like McCawley's distinction between external versus internal criteria for classification.  What I mean by "downstairs" concerns how a constituent combines with its sisters, while "upstairs" concerns how the mother of that constituent combines.  As for example, in "Dribbling rapidly is difficult" you might classify "dribbling" as a downstairs verb since it is modified by an adjective sister, but as an upstairs noun on the grounds that its mother is an argument NP of the predicate "is difficult".  (Actually, though, it's not really a noun at all.)